# Coded UI & Selenium - different execution speed depending on where mouse pointer is

Tags: c#, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So, working in C#. I have a CSS-based drop-down menu. I open the menu, then grab a reference to it using FindElement by CSSSelector. I then grab the contents of the list using FindElements, again by CSSSelector.

Now here's where it get's interesting. I iterate the list, based on a file I have open in a streamreader.

Looks something like:

```
list = driver.FindElement(By.CSSSelector("dropdown-menu"));
list_items = list.FindElements(By.CSSSelector("LI > A"));

int row = 0;
while (data_file.read())
{
  iWebElement item = list_items[row];
  string label = item.text;
  string url = item.getattribute("href");
  assert.areequal("something", label);
  assert.areequal("something else", url);
  row++;
}
```

Now here's the thing: if the mouse pointer is placed over the drop-down, while this is executing, item.text returns value and the test succeeds. If the pointer is anywhere else, item.text will be blank and the test fails. Trying to understand what's going on, and taking a clue from the fact that though the test would fail when running, but would succeed while stepping, I modified the code with a loop:

```
while (data_file.read())
{
  iWebElement item = list_items[row];
  string label = item.text;
  while (label == "")
  {
    label = item.text;
  }
  string url = item.getattribute("href");
  assert.areequal("something", label);
  assert.areequal("something else", url);
  row++;
}
```

Now the test will always succeed, but if the pointer is not on the control it is SIGNIFICANTLY slower... we're talking a factor of 4 or 5... then when the pointer IS on the control. By wrapping a timer around this, I find that it typically takes between 2 and 4 seconds before .text returns anything but an empty string... sometimes longer.

Again, this delay only seems to apply when the mouse pointer is not over the drop-down. Otherwise, the value appears to be there instantaneously.

Can anyone suggest a possible explanation for why it's behaving this way, and a possible approach to solving it?

BTW, I'm not finding any difference between:

```
item = list_items[row];
label = item.text;
```

and

```
label = list_items[row].text;
```

Nor does .getattribute("value") produce any faster results than .text.

Answer (score 0):

As for why the menus are acting this way, it's hard to tell with the code you've provided.  If you could provide the code that displays your menu, that might help.  As for solutions, there are a couple.

1. The label could be taking longer to display because of the while loop itself - it's just going crazy grabbing the text over and over very quickly.  A better solution would be to wait for the element to be present.  This may make your code run faster.  See the [Selenium Website](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) for information on using WebDriverWait.
2. Alternatively, there is an "ugly" solution.  You can just move the mouse to the menu with Selenium, to make sure the menu is always displayed when you need it.  I've adapted some code from [here](http://learnseleniumtesting.com/mouse-hover-and-other-mouse-events-in-webdriver/) as an example:

   ```
   OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions builder = new 
           builder.MoveToElement(list).Build().Perform();
   ```

Hope this helps!